# How do I disable trailing-comma tslint rule in SPFx scaffolding?

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts, spfx-tooling

I ran the current Yeoman SharePoint generator, and got the following ts-lint file in the config directory (with a few minor tweaks added).

From what I can tell the trailing-comma rule should be disabled (it's set to false), but it's not.  I'm still getting red squigglies when I don't have a trailing comma.

What am I missing?  Thanks!  :-)

```
  "$schema": "https://dev.office.com/json-schemas/core-build/tslint.schema.json",
  // Display errors as warnings
  "displayAsWarning": true,
  // The TSLint task may have been configured with several custom lint rules
  // before this config file is read (for example lint rules from the tslint-microsoft-contrib
  // project). If true, this flag will deactivate any of these rules.
  "removeExistingRules": true,
  // When true, the TSLint task is configured with some default TSLint "rules.":
  "useDefaultConfigAsBase": false,
  // Since removeExistingRules=true and useDefaultConfigAsBase=false, there will be no lint rules
  // which are active, other than the list of rules below.
  "lintConfig": {
    // Opt-in to Lint rules which help to eliminate bugs in JavaScript
    "rules": {
      "class-name": false,
      "export-name": false,
      "forin": false,
      "label-position": false,
      "member-access": true,
      "no-arg": false,
      "no-console": false,
      "no-construct": false,
//      "no-duplicate-switch-case": true,
      "no-duplicate-variable": true,
      "no-eval": false,
      "no-function-expression": true,
      "no-internal-module": true,
      "no-shadowed-variable": true,
      "no-switch-case-fall-through": true,
      "no-unnecessary-semicolons": true,
      "no-unused-expression": true,
      "no-use-before-declare": true,
      "no-with-statement": true,
      "semicolon": true,
      "trailing-comma": false,
      "typedef": false,
      "typedef-whitespace": false,
      "use-named-parameter": true,
      "typeof-compare": true,
      "variable-name": false,
      "whitespace": false
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: can you also share the code snippet where you are getting this error ?

Comment: @GautamSheth - edited post to include screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://joelfmrodrigues.wordpress.com/2017/12/06/tslint-spfx/

> I like to use the TSLint extension on Visual Studio Code to
>   immediately flag errors. This is very useful as you can see them
>   before you save and wait for a build task to flag them. What I don’t
>   like, is that the TSLint config file (tslint.config) is generated
>   inside the config folder by the SPFx Yeoman generator.
>
> When you open a project folder with Visual Studio Code, TSLint
>   (assuming that it’s installed) will by default look for a
>   tslint.config file at the root of that folder and use that
>   configuration to display information on the Problems window.
>
> Guess what? If the file is not there, TSLint won’t display any issues,
>   which is the default for any SharePoint Framework solution.
>
> If you thought that the solution is to simply copy the file from the
>   config folder to the root folder, so that TSLint works on VS Code and
>   also on the gulp task, shame on you  duplication is never the
>   solution for a developer
>
> Fortunately TSLint supports that (and a lot more if you look at the
>   documentation), so in order to solve the problem you simply need to
>   tell TSLint where to find the correct configuration.
>
> For the following to work, you need the TSLint extension for VS Code
>   and TSLint installed globally (npm install -g tslint).
>
> Start by creating an empty tslint.json file at the root folder of your
>   SPFx project.
>
> [image]
>
> TSLint will load this file automatically as it uses the expected
>   config name
>
> Then simply add a rulesDirectory property to it that instructs TSLint
>   to get the correct config options from the config folder created by
>   the Yeoman generator
>
> `{   "rulesDirectory": "./config" }`
>
> That’s it! Now close and reopen VS
>   Code and you should see warnings and errors on the Problems window.